# Is it safe to use this charging cable for my HP PC?

Tags: charger

Recently, my HP PC PSU and the cable had burnt up.
I have tried looking for a charger with kind of the same voltage, power and amps.

So my previous chargers (HP) details are given:

```
INPUT: 
100-240V 
1.5 A
50-60 Hz

OUTPUT: 
19.5 V 
4.62 A
90 W MAX
```

Given below is what I found to be a new charger (ASUS) with following details:

```
INPUT:
100-240V
1.2 A 
50-60 Hz

OUTPUT:
20V 
4.5 A 
90 W MAX
```

Now, here's the question, can I use the Lenovo charger for my HP PC?

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate, but I can't find a suitable question/answer...

Answer (score 2):

In summary:

- If you can, get a new supply with the same manufacturer & model number
- Input voltage must suit your local supply
- Output voltage must match the equipment's requirements
- Output current / power must match, or be greater than the previous supply (or equipment's requirements)
- Check the polarity is correct and the connector fits

---

DC power supplies are characterised in a few major ways:

- Input - Voltage / Current / Power
- Output - Voltage / Current / Power

#### Input

- Voltage - **You just need to make sure that this suits your local power - e.g: UK is around 230v AC, US is around 110v AC.** Many modern switched mode power supplies can tolerate a wide input voltage (e.g: 100-240v AC).
- Current / Power - these are largely irrelevant at this point, just make sure that you don't expect to draw high current (larger Amperage) though an undersized fuse / flex / socket.

#### Output

- Voltage - **This is critically important and should match the device's requirements.** If your previous supply had a specified 19.5v output, then you should get a replacement with a 19.5v output. 0.5v difference (20v) might "*work*", but it'll be operating in the tolerances rather than in the designed range. As the voltage difference increases, components may get hotter, have reduced life span, or stop working immediately.
- Current / Power - **This figure specifies the power supply's upper limit - the new supply must provide the same or more power.** Your original supply was able to deliver *up to* 4.62 A as its rated 19.5v output (which is ~90 W, `P=IV`), but this doesn't mean the device will consume this much current all the time. If your new supply is able to deliver more current / power, try not to get one that is too much larger.
- Connector - The most common DC connector is a ["*barrel jack*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coaxial_power_connector), but there is a range of sizes (both outer diameter and pin) that can make things frustrating. There are a number of standards to help designers select the correct size connector for the voltage / current (and thus ensure that nothing too drastic goes wrong), but they are rarely adhered to. Also, larger manufacturers (e.g: Dell / HP / Lenovo) do funny things like put the pin on the "*other*" end, providing a third conductor, or use a square USB-shaped connector.

[image: power connectors]

- Polarity - Something that is often missed is that the connector will have a polarity - e.g: the center of the barrel will be positive, and the outer surface will be negative. If you get a replacement power supply with the incorrect polarity, then you'll effectively be providing a negative voltage (-20v) instead, which will most likely cause permanent damage immediately. While center-positive is very common, it's not exclusive. Look for a symbol like these:

[image: polarity symbols]

---

I mentioned that oversizing the new supply is okay... consider Dell's range of laptops - ultra portable with long battery life, to portable workstations.

Many of them (especially in commercial setting) run from a supply that provides the same voltage and connector - but the less power hungry laptops are shipped with lower wattage adapters (e.g: 65W), while the more power hungry laptops are shipped with higher wattage adapters (e.g: 130W).

- Using a 65W adapter on a device designed for 130W will (in some cases) be "*okay*", but you'll find that the battery won't charge, or the performance will be significantly limited.
- Using the 130W adapter on a device designed for 65W will be fine, and there will be no issues.